Can soil be too loose?
I took over a garden property and want to plant my own vegetables. I created a small field by removing a grassy area, and in doing so lost quite a bit of the existing soil (stuck to the roots). Also, on this property is a very old compost that hasn't been maintained in years, and unfortunately is littered with small pieces of trash. For unrelated reasons I need to completely remove this compost (and I will replace it with a new one).
To boost the amount of soil on my field I thought to use the old compost, and in order to remove the trash pieces I sieve the soil bits by bits to find and take out as much trash as possible. This now left me with nice blackish soil, but it's very very loose.
This leads me to my question: Can soil be too loose?

After adding a lot of this soil on my field I tried watering it a lot, and after a sunny day the top layer looks like this crust. I'm unsure whether this is okay.

A small related question: By doing this, will the large amount of compost and smaller amount of humus cause problems?

Yes soil can be too loose, which would be sand.  But this isn't it.  The soli required depends on what you are growing.  If you are growing from seeds, then the packet will tell you what sort of soil is required.
But it does look like the soil needs some mulch or organic matter.
